# How to Redirect not seo Friendly url

Tags: .htaccess

Please help to redirect this url `http://tanyahelfandblog.com/?p=86` to this url: `http://www.tanyahelfand.com/what-is-a-prenuptial-agreement/` in a `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 0):

If its just a single redirect, you can use something like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} p=86
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://tanyahelfand.com/what-is-a-prenuptial-agreement/? [L,R=301]
```

If you want it for a lot of links, its better if you use some other technique (like storing redirects in the DB).

Comment: He wants to redirect it to a different domain too. Initial domain name is different from the one in second line

Comment: If you're using WordPress,you can use a plugin like this one http://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

Comment: The domain isn't relevant, he can use a different domain in RewriteRule. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Keep in mind that this will redirect EVERY page in the site with `?p=86` appended to it. If you want to tweak it to only work on the root path, you need to add another `RewriteCond` condition